# How is Dru-Zod / General Zod supposed to be born?

Tags: krypton

From the TV Show Krypton, Dru-Zod is the son of Seg-El and Lyta-Zod. In the last episode, Seg manages to trap Brainiac inside the Phantom Zone but unfortunately Brainiac manages to take Seg along with him just before the portal gets destroyed. Shouldn't Dru-Zod by wiped from existence because Seg is now in the Phantom Zone? Or did Lyta-Zod get pregnant before Seg got taken into the Phantom Zone?

Comment: WHy Phantom Zone will wipe his lineage?

Comment: @Memor-X Both of these are completely different questions.

Comment: @Sujit actually they aren't as both are asking about how Dru is alive despite how the past is changed and the answer to the latter question will no doubt answer this question which is what closing as duplicate is for, not just if the questions are the same but if they also have the same answer